# Global default value for Objective-C block

Tags: objective-c

I've got an initializer that takes a block. I'd also like a convenience initializer that doesn't require the block, and instead uses a global default instance of the block:

`ABCDef.m`:

```
#import "ABCDefaultReader.h"

@implementation ABCDef {
  NSString *(^_reader)(NSString *name);
}

- (instancetype)initWithReader:(NSString *(^)(NSString *name))reader {
  self = [super init];
  if (self) {
    _reader = reader;
  }
  return self;
}

- (instancetype)init {
  // ABCDefaultReader imported from ABCDefaultReader.h
  return [self initWithReader:ABCDefaultReader];
}
```

`ABCDefaultReader.h`:

```
extern NSString *(^ABCDefaultReader)(NSString *name);
```

`ABCDefaultReader.m`:

```
#import "ABCDefaultReader.h"

extern NSString *(^ABCDefaultReader)(NSString *name) = ^NSString *(NSString *name) {
  // ...
}
```

This fails to build because `'extern' variable has an initializer` (I'm using `-Werror`):

```
ABCDefaultReader.m:3:36: error: 'extern' variable has an initializer [-Werror,-Wextern-initializer]
extern NSString *(^ABCDefaultReader)(NSString *name) = ^NSString *(NSString *name) {
                                                        ^
1 error generated.
```

1. Why is it a problem to have an initializer?
2. What's a good way to have a default, constant block defined in a separate file, and referenced from my implementation class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Objective-C (or, more accurately, in C), when you have a global like that,

- The actual global variable should be in the source file (the `.m` Objective-C file, or `.c` in the case of C). Here you can include the the initialization. But no `extern` qualifier should be used.
- The `.h` should have the `extern` declaration (without the initialization) to expose this global to other compilation units.

Let's consider a simpler example (to take the syntactic noise of Objective-C blocks out of the equation).

Thus, we declare a global in the `.m` file ...

```objectivec
//  Foo.m

#import "Foo.h"

NSInteger baz = 42;

@implementation Foo

@end
```

... and we expose that global in its `.h` header:

```objectivec
//  Foo.h

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

extern NSInteger baz;

@interface Foo : NSObject

@end
```

Now we can access that global from other files:

```objectivec
//  Bar.m

#import "Bar.h"
#import "Foo.h"

@implementation Bar

- (void)qux {
    NSLog(@"%ld", (long)baz); // 42
}

@end
```

---

You asked:

> 1. Why is it a problem to have an initializer?

The `extern` effectively means “there is a global implemented elsewhere”. Initializing it there does not make sense.

> 2. What's a good way to have a default, constant block defined in a separate file, and referenced from my implementation class?

While you can use the proper `extern` pattern, outlined above, I would advise against using globals at all. I might have a `class` property for this block. Or I might have an instance property for this block and then put it in some shared instance (a shared instance that you inject where needed or, in very narrow cases, perhaps a singleton). It is hard to say in your particular situation without more context.

But we would generally avoid polluting the global namespace.

---

By the way, you have described this block as a “constant”. If you didn’t really mean “constant”, then disregard the following, but if so, read on:

As you’ve defined this global, it is mutable and can be replaced by anywhere in your code. If it really is a constant, you should include `const` qualifier:

```objectivec
// .h

extern NSString *(^const ABCDefaultReader)(NSString *);

// .m

extern NSString *(^const ABCDefaultReader)(NSString *) = ^(NSString *string) {
    // do something with `string`

    NSString *result = ...
    return result;
}
```

And this, of course, begs the question of why you would use a block at all if it is a constant. The value of blocks is that the caller can supply a block of code of which the called routine will avail itself. E.g., if we wanted to call some Objective-C method, we might just create an class method:

```objectivec
// Foo.h

@interface Foo: NSObject

+ (NSString *)bar:(NSString *)input;

@end
```

And

```objectivec
// Foo.m

@implementation Foo

+ (NSString *)bar:(NSString *)input {
    NSString *output = ...
    return output;
}

@end
```

And then you’d call it like so:

```objectivec
// Baz.m

@implementation Baz

- (void)someRoutine {
    NSString *result = [Foo bar:@"baz"];
    // do something with `result`
}

@end
```

This is a routine that can be called anywhere, without using globals, doesn’t require instantiating the object in question, but the method is nicely namespaced.

Comment: Ahhh if I hadn't posted w/ my work account I'd be able to upvote as well as accept. Thank you so much!

Comment: The reasons I thought a block would be appropriate are (1) I want the caller to be able to override the "read" behavior (i.e. instead of doing the default I/O, just return an in-memory value), (2) I come from JS where we have nice functions and not-so-nice classes 

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `extern` inside of the .m file. "extern" means "this is defined somewhere else," but you're defining it right here.

Comment: Thank you! I if I hadn't accidentally posted from my work account, I'd have the karma to give you an upvote.